# Cannot allocate memory for struct, error: request for member '****' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am recently doing a school homework and I am stuck, in creating dynamic array of structs. I was looking everywhere, but no answer helped me, so can you please look at my code and help me, what is wrong?
I keep getting error: 
C:\kof\test1\main.c|29|error: request for member 'lenght' in something not a structure or union|

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct time
{
int mi;
int ho;
int dn;
int me;
int ro;
};

struct journey
{
int lenght;
struct time zac;
struct time kon;
int tank;
int price;
};


int main ()
{
struct journey *fail;
struct journey *b=(struct journey*) malloc (1*sizeof(struct journey));
fail=b;
fail.lenght=5;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably `lenght` should be `length`, although in what you are posting here you have the typo twice

Comment: You need to read about the difference between the `.` and `->` operator. Check e.g. [this member-access reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access).

Comment: lOl, thank you Joachim, that actually helped :D I feel so stupid now, but a little bit smarter too :D
Btw. the allocation of memory is alright? I am not sure, still a newbie in a field of dynamic memory :D

Comment: The allocation is okay, but multiplying with one is kind of pointless. Also, in C you should not cast the return value of functions returning `void *` (like `malloc` does). And of course you should check that the allocation actually succeeded before using the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `*fail` is a pointer of type struct journey, you access its elements using the '`->`' notation and not using the `.` notation as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)